# Flex AdvancedDataGrid slow on performance while being resized

Tags: apache-flex, performance, advanceddatagrid, renderer

I have a AdvancedDataGrid which is placed inside a resizable container (custom panel) and fixed at 100% width and height. Datagrid has about 100 rows and 15 columns. When I try to resize the container datagrid kinda freezes. I understand that while resizing the whole redraw process is being held in my datagrid but are there any ways of optimizing this behavior? Can I force datagrid postpone the whole update process while I am resizing the outter container?

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite AdvancedDataGrid class function invalidateDisaplyList to your own, but you should to go deeper until UIComponent to handle it in right way, so you could have another way: just while resizing clean dataProvider of Grid and after event will be completed set dataProvider back.

Comment: thanks for reply. I like the idea with cleaning the dataprovider but while resizing the panel users should see what is going on with the grid and what column are visible as they resize.

Comment: if so detect the maximal width&height of component and row height and left only these firsts items in dataProvider, how do you think?